# Node.js + Selenium How to parse html properly

Tags: node.js, parsing, selenium

I would like to traverse through all **th** elements on my page:

[image]

The path to the **th** elements is **div[id='specs-list']/table/tbody/tr/th**:

My script is:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
    build();

driver.get('http://www.gsmarena.com');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('sName')).sendKeys('iphone 4s');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('quick-search-button')).click();


driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//div[@id='specs-list']/table/tbody/tr/th")).then(function(elem){
    console.log(elem.getText());
});
```

But I get:

```
drobazko@drobazko:~/www$ node first_test.js
{ then: [Function: then],
  cancel: [Function: cancel],
  isPending: [Function: isPending] }
```

Instead text `General`
Questions are:
 1. How can I get correct text string?
 2. How Can I traverse through many **th** elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 - How can I get correct text string?

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//div[@id='specs-list']/table/tbody/tr/th")).getText().then(function(textValue){
    console.log(textValue);
});
```

Or

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//div[@id='specs-list']/table/tbody/tr/th")).then(function(elem){
    elem.getText().then(function(textValue) {
        console.log(textValue);
    });
});
```

Why?

Both findElement and getText() return you a promise. You would get similar result if you try to console.log(driver.findElement(....))

2 - How Can I traverse through many th elements?

```
driver.findElements(webdriver.By.xpath("//div[@id='specs-list']/table/tbody/tr/th")).then(function(elems){
    elems.forEach(function (elem) {
        elem.getText().then(function(textValue){
            console.log(textValue);
        });
    });
});
```