# Click on random link via node.js and webdriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have some page with different products and should select randomly one of them.
I have made test on javascript but have problems when trying to write it using node.js and selenium.

On my test page I got next structure

```
<div class="products">
    <table width="600" cellspacing="6">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="phones-59.php"></a>
                </td>
                <td>...
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>...</tr>
...
```

So next example is working on javascript and I got all links I need

```
   links = document.getElementById('products').getElementsByTagName('a');
```

then I use random and select some link, something like this (got example here [Choosing a link at random](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/918-javascript-choosing-a-link-at-random))

```
   randomlink = Math.round(Math.random() * (links.length+1));
   links[randomlink].click();
```

Nothing special, but when I have tried such trick in node.js I can't access to links. I got errors when trying to use click() and other functions

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('products')).findElements(webdriver.By.tagName('a'));
```

So how I can click on random link in my "products" block?
Thanks

PS I have copied "unique selector' from firefox developers console, but have no idea how to use it in right way (I have tried use xpath without success)

```
"products > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1)"
```

**update**
I have also tried such construction and got correct number of links, but can't access to them

```
ll = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('products'));
lk = ll.findElements(webdriver.By.tagName('a')).then(function(txt) {
    logger.info("lk length: " + txt.length); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very weird :) but it works

Example for Bing.Com

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var logger = require('winston');

driver.get('http://bing.com');
driver.findElements(webdriver.By.tagName('a')).then(function(elems){
    logger.info("links count: " + elems.length);
    rnd = Math.round(Math.random() * (elems.length+1));
    logger.info("rnd number: " + rnd);

    elems[rnd].getText().then(function(textValue){
        logger.info("link name: " + textValue);
    });

    elems[rnd].then(function (elem) {
        elem.click();
    });
});
```

I found answer here [Node.js + Selenium How to parse html properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852310/node-js-selenium-how-to-parse-html-properly/24857032#24857032)

Comment: apparently "elems" should have a randomElement property which would make this a lot simpler

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit the html and give each one of the links their own unique IDs?  I would do that and then create an array that contains all of the IDs.  Choose a random ID and then use driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id(randomID[x])).click();

If you don't have permissions to edit the html you could do something similar with xpath.  Add all the unique xpath selectors to an array and instead of findElement(webdriver.by.id(randomID[x])) use findelement(webdriver.by.xpath(randomXpath[x]));

Sorry if I didn't get the syntax entirely correct... I usually use selenium with C#.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you show example on c# how to add ID to my links, if I haven't access to edit source html?

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I was getting at.  You can't add an HTML id to the tag without access to the source.  Try my second method, on the page you are trying to test, manually get the xpath of all of the possibilities and hard code them into an array. Pick a random index from that array and do findelement(webdriver.by.xpath()) instead of by ID.