# How to find all links on a page in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm studing with node.js (webdriver) right now, and can't understand some issues. I have tried to search in internet and didn't find any examples of task I needed.
For example, how I can log to console all links from the page (bing.com for example)?
I don't understand why simple javascript constructions like this

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

doesn't work in node.js.

If I use

```
findElement(webdriver.By.tagName('a'))
```

I got only first link on the page, why? Arrays not available in nodejs?

If it's not possible, which module should be used (example). For current moment, I have the impression that for even a simple functionality an additional modules required, therefore all my first steps failed, because I'm trying do anything like in javascript.

Thanks

Comment: `findElement` != `findElements`; it is appropriate that a function with a name that implies a singular result should only return a single element.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this, but if I use FindElements I got as result or error or something like this (not the desired links):

`{ then: [Function: then],
  cancel: [Function: cancel],
  isPending: [Function: isPending],
  errback: [Function: reject],
  driver_: `

Comment: That looks like a Promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found answer on my question and answered in this topic [Click on random link via node.js and webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298669/click-on-random-link-via-node-js-and-webdriver/)

Example of code (thanks to [Nguyen Vu Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2090769/nguyen-vu-hoang))

```
driver.findElements(webdriver.By.tagName("a")).then(function(elems){
    elems.forEach(function (elem) {
        elem.getText().then(function(textValue){
            console.log(textValue);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please [documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebElement.html) about findElements

```
findElements ( locator ) ⇒ !webdriver.promise.Promise
```

Schedules a command to find all of the descendants of this element that match the given search criteria.
**Parameters**

```
locator: !(webdriver.Locator|webdriver.By.Hash|Function)
```

The locator strategy to use when searching for the elements.

**Returns**

A promise that will resolve to an array of WebElements.

Comment: I saw this, but can't (don't know how) use on practice.

Comment: Have an example of how to use such a Promise result to solve the initial problem?