# Click on second element of the list in node js in selenium web driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

> menuList = findElements(By.cssSelector(".menuList"));
>
> List < WebElement > menuButtons =
>   menuList.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul>li>a"));
>           menuButtons.get(1).click();

I want to do this thing in nodeJs, what should I write ?

The HTML Hierarchy is as follows -

```
List
   - List 1.1
        -- List 1.1 a
        -- List 1.1 b
   - List 1.2
        -- List 1.2 a
        -- List 1.2 b
```

I am doing automation testing in nodeJs by using selenium web driver. 
So, I want to click on " List 1.2 a " link in my code. How do I access that element?

Comment: What you are asking is not clear. You realize nodejs is a server-side environment and your query seems to be regarding client side scripting?

Comment: I want to access second element of the list in node js . I am using selenium web driver for automation testing. I want to click that element and navigate to that page.

Comment: did you try googling selenium webdriver locate html elements nodejs? [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298669/click-on-random-link-via-node-js-and-webdriver) looks to almost have your answer for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this?

```
driver.findElements(By.css('.menuList ul>li>a')).then(function(elems){
    elems[1].then(function (elem) {
        elem.click();
    });
});
```

Sources:

- [similar example maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298669/click-on-random-link-via-node-js-and-webdriver)
- [docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html)

Comment: This is throwing this error -    TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Comment: okay I modified it to look more like the example code I looked at, maybe it works now, but really i don't know anything about selenium webdriver.. this was just to give you ideas so you can look at the docs/other examples yourself and figure this out